# How to prevent system mouse cursor movement in a C++ applicatioin with custom cursor?

Tags: c++, mouse, mouseevent, wndproc

I am writing an OpenGL/DX application in which I read `WM_INPUT` messages in `WndProc()` to move a custom mouse cursor. The system mouse cursor is hidden via `ShowCursor(false)` when it is over/in the application's window.

The problem is that the system mouse cursor still moves when I move the mouse. So both cursors (the normal system cursor and the custom cursor in my application) are moving at the same time. The same goes for mouse clicks too.

So my question is: how can I prevent the system mouse cursor to move (and click) when the application is running, so that only the custom mouse cursor is functional?

Comment: Alternatively, you can just display your custom cursor at the position of the hidden system cursor.

Comment: @BlueWanderer: I think that would not solve my issue. The problem is that the system mouse cursor is fully functional while my application is running. Hence when the user clicks with the mouse in the application, the click is also done by the system mouse cursor. If that system cursor is over a button of another window for example, then that button is clicked as well. This is obviously not what I want. There must be a "default" way of how to approach that problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor is just for display. Hiding the default cursor and drawing your own one won't affect the move and click.

I guess there are two possibilities what you are doing:

1. If you just want to display a custom cursor, you should just hide the system cursor when the mouse is inside your window. So the user knows what he/she is doing when the cursor is outside your window. Or you can constrain the mouse inside your window with ClipMouse.
2. If you are handling the mouse completely by yourself with something like DirectInput, again, you should use ClipMouse.

Comment: Great, thanks, `ClipCursor()` (I guess this is what you meant) did the trick for me!